# Many To Many vs One to Many

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to set user permissions to edit other users profile.

What I want is to be able to set for each user which user can be handled.
So, let's say we have 5 users: A, B, C, D, E

I want A to be able to handle B, C and D.
I want B to be able to handle A, E, C.
And so on...

Is this a one-to-many or a many-to-many relation?

I'm not able to understand it because, it seems to me a one-to-many since there is one user having multiple users. But since the user itself can be handled by another one, makes me think it could be a many-to-many.

What questions should I ask to myself to identify the right relation?

Comment: A handle B, C, D, etc. But A can be manipulated by several?

Answer (score 5):

This is a many to many relation, as one account can edit many, and many accounts can edit one account.

Example:

```
A can edit ABC  
B can edit AC 
C can edit BC
```

So A can be edited by multiple accounts (or belongs to multiple accounts), and can edit multiple accounts (or has multiple accounts)

Answer (score 4):

Let's work through your problem and see how to identify the relationship.

When you're writing the code that will check whether a user is authorized, you are going to have two main pieces of data: The user that is performing the edit and the user that is being edited. So, the question your application will be asking is *"can user A edit user B?"*

Ignoring the semantics of relationships for a moment, think about how you'd look up the answer to that question:

```
table can_edit:
  requestor_id | edited_id | permission
  =====================================
  User A       | User B    | YES
  User A       | User C    | YES
  User A       | User D    | YES
  User A       | User E    | NO
  User B       | User A    | YES
  User B       | User C    | YES
  User B       | User D    | NO
  etc...
```

Using this lookup table, you can determine who has access to edit whom. But, look again at what this table is describing. Since you're looking up the answer to a YES/NO question, you can express it more simply:

```
table can_edit:
  requestor_id | edited_id | permission
  =====================================
  User A       | User B    | YES
  User A       | User C    | YES
  User A       | User D    | YES
  User B       | User A    | YES
  User B       | User C    | YES
  etc...
```

Here we've dropped the `NO` permissions. Now we can ask, *"Do we have an entry in `can_edit` that matches our permission check?"* If we perform a lookup and the row exists, then we can allow the access.

Now, since the `permission` column will always be `YES`, it doesn't make much sense to include it. So now we have a table that is basically a list of user ID relationships.

At this point we can draw out what the relationships look like using a database diagram:

```
users:
  user_id  <-----+
  email          |       can_edit:
  pass_digest    +-------- requestor_id
               +========== edited_id
users:         |
  user_id <====+
  email
  pass_digest
```

If we look at the example diagrams in the [rails association guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), we can see that our diagram closely matches both `has_many :through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`. These both describe **many-to-many** relationships.

As far as the implementation details go, you'll notice that both *"can user A edit user B?"* and *"is user B a friend of user A?"* are essentially the same question, just using different terms for the relationship. With that knowledge, you'll find that volumes have been written about how to define this **self-referential `has_many :through` relationship**, such as [this excellent screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast) by Ryan Bates.

Answer (score 2):

if you are not sure, i recommend that you read the guides about rails associations. there are some nice examples and schema pictures, that illustrate the problems:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Answer (score 0):

This is a many-to-many relation because in your example `A` is on both sides of the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I guess is a M2M relationship because in the table *How many*? more than one is related with *Hoy many* more than one.